# How to define get method in Anypoint studio if queryParam is defined?

Tags: api, rest, mulesoft, anypoint-studio

Im trying to make a get method in Anypoint studio. I have already defined raml file with get method that looks something like this:

```
/kupci:
  get:
    queryParameters:
      active:
        required: false
        enum:
          - "true"
          - "false"
```

I want to make a get flow that returns data from mysql database with 2 options:

1. if i have defined queryParam return everything from the database based of that condition
2. if not defined, just return everything from database

Comment: What is the issue that you are having while trying to create the flow? What have you tried? Questions are expected to be specific. Kindly read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask for tips on how to improve your question.

Comment: I put choice endpoint in my flow with when and default condition.In when, i wrote condition like attributes.queryParams.active==true or attributes.queryParams.active==false but it does not work when i send get method with querypara, it goes straight to the default which returns all data from the table

Comment: That is probably because in the RAML you have defined the queryParam as a string. But in the choice router you are comparing it with boolean

Comment: Please add the explanation to the question, include the XML of the flow, and the input.

Answer (score 0):

You just need a simple if else condition wherever you are creating your select query, and add a `where` clause if `active` is non empty.

```js
SELECT field1, field2, ... FROM table
++ if(!isEmpty(attributes.queryParams.active)) 'WHERE active = $(attributes.queryParams.active)'
   else ''
```

Note: You might need to change the above query if the datatype of the column `active` is Boolean. For example:
`WHERE active IS $(attributes.queryParams.active)`

You need to wrap this around the `#[]` script tag when writing in `db:select` as mentioned in the [mule database connector docs](https://docs.mulesoft.com/db-connector/1.13/database-connector-select#configure-dynamic-queries-in-the-select-operation)

Comment: Can you show how would that look like in anypoint studio, because when i put this sql syntax in my select endpoint it shows me some errors?

Comment: You just need to wrap it around in `#[]` scrip element as mentioned in this document https://docs.mulesoft.com/db-connector/1.13/database-connector-select#configure-dynamic-queries-in-the-select-operation